# Set of strictly monotonic functions from $[0,1]$ into $[0,1]$ form a group.

Tags: group-theory

To show that the set of strictly monotonic functions from $[0,1]$ into $[0,1]$ form a group under composition of mapping.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you list the things that you have to prove in order to show that this set is a group under composition? If not, you need to start there.

Comment: What have you tried? This follows almost immediately when you write out the definitions of a group. The slightly tricky aspect is remembering that the group operation is composition, and not point wise addition.

Comment: s/into/onto/g ?

Answer (score 6):

This does not form a group.  Any such map that isn't surjective won't have an inverse.

Comment: I think the "from $[0,1]$ into $[0,1]$" is a misstatement, and the term onto is meant as opposed to into - in which case, the set is of surjective monotonic maps.

Answer (score 0):

To show a structure ($S, \circ$) forms a group, you must show that $\circ$ is an associative binary operation on $S$. The set is trivially nonempty, and the composition of functions is associative. If $f,g$ are monotonic, then if $x<y$, $g(x)<g(y)$ and $f(g(x)) < f(g(y)) $, and so $(f \circ g)(x) < (f \circ g)(y)$ is monotonic, which shows that $\circ$ forms a binary operation on $S$. All you have to do now is show that $S$ possesses an identity, and that for all $f \in S$, there exists $f^{-1} \in S$. For the identity, think about the form of the function $I$ if $I \circ f = f \circ I = f$ (this shouldn't be hard, $I$ is a simple, well-known function); as for the inverse $f^{-1}$ - it must be monotonic, and when composed with $f$ yield $I$.

Hint: A strictly monotonic function $f$ is a bijection, and so there exists an $f^{-1}$.